# How to manually install a package into anaconda's python distribution?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I manually compiled and installed OpenCV, but the installation process installed it to the systems python distribution (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7`).

I normally use my anaconda python distribution (`~/bin/anaconda2`).

I see a `cv2.so` file in the system python distribution at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, and all of the OpenCV file are installed at `/usr/local`.

Is there a way I can move this installation to the anaconda package manually? Is it as simple as moving the `cv2.so` file and updating my `PYTHONPATH` with `/usr/local`?

The anaconda package of OpenCV doesn't install dependencies like `ffmpeg`, hence my need to build from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem. In my case I resolved it by copying the `cv2.pyd` file to the following path: `C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages`.

I restarted my system and was able to use OpenCV using the Spyder IDE available in Anaconda.

For your second question regarding `ffmpeg`, [THIS LINK](http://kronoskoders.logdown.com/posts/256664-installing-opencv-and-ffmpeg-on-windows) will help.